# Block inline behaviour of youtube video

Tags: android, html, youtube, cordova

I'm developing an html5 + phonegap + jQueryMobile app...in a page i have an embedded video from youtube with the code below

```
<iframe class="vidpif1" width="100%" height="268px" src="" seamless></iframe>
```

(the src value is generated by JQ)

```
 $('#DIV iframe').attr('src' , 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXX?rel=0;3&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0?html5=1?qv=large?theme=light&color=white');
```

when i click the play button the video starts inline in android 4.2.2 while in Android 2.3.6 it starts in the default player (with black background)...how i can block the inline behaviour?!?
thanks